# a ≡ b mod m a^c ≡ b^c mod m?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Assume that a ≡ b mod m. Let c be a positive integer. Is it always true that $a^c$ ≡ $b^c$ mod m ? I think it's true but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Induction.$\,\!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\equiv b$ mod  $m$ means that $m \mid a-b$. Now, it is well known that $a-b \mid a^c-b^c$. So, how can you conclude that $a^c\equiv b^c$ mod  $m$?

Comment: It's because $a^c-b^c=(a-b)\left(a^{c-1}+a^{c-2}b+\cdots+b^{c-1}\right)$.